# How can I determine the bus clock programatically or via command line in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, clock, wmi, bus

I want to write a program that displays some system information. How can I programmatically determine the clock speed of the bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bus clock can be determined using the WMI. The relevant class is `Win32_Processor`, and the property `ExtClock` provides the bus clock in MHz.

WMI objects can be accessed via command line using `wmic`:

```
C:\>wmic path Win32_Processor get ExtClock /VALUE
ExtClock=100
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the speed of memory (RAM), also called Bus Speed of memory, use:

```
wmic memorychip get speed
```

The number of answers you get will depend on the RAM configuration,
but all answers should be identical.